# Alignment of the widgets in Python Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, widget

I'm going crazy with this stupid problem. As you can see in running this simple code, the "combobox" widget is not in line with the other "entry" widgets. Where am I wrong?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()

frame = Frame(root)
frame.grid()

x = Label(frame, text="alpha", width = 8, anchor = W)
x.grid(row=1, columnspan=1)
x = Entry(frame,  width = 24)
x.grid(row=1, column=2, columnspan=2,  sticky=W)

x = Label(frame, text="beta", width = 8, anchor = W)
x.grid(row=2, columnspan=1)
x = Entry(frame,  width = 24)
x.grid(row=2, column=2, columnspan=2,  sticky=W)

x = Label(frame, text="gamma", width = 8, anchor = W)
x.grid(row=3, columnspan=1)
x = Entry(frame, width = 7, justify = 'center')
x.grid(row=3, column=2, columnspan=1, sticky=W)
#x = ttk.Combobox(frame, width = 4, justify = "center")
#x.grid(row=3, column=3, columnspan=1, sticky=W)

x = Label(frame, text="delta", width = 8, anchor = W)
x.grid(row=4, columnspan=1)
x = ttk.Combobox(frame, width=20)
x.grid(row=4, column=2, columnspan=2,  sticky=W)

x = Label(frame, text="epsilon", width = 8, anchor = W)
x.grid(row=5, columnspan=1)
x = Entry(frame,  width = 24)
x.grid(row=5, column=2, columnspan=2,  sticky=W)

mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Which combobox?  Your code has two. And what sort of alignment are you asking about? Vertically aligned? Left edges aligned? Right edges? Both? All?

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear. The combobox named "delta" is not left aligned with the "Entry" widgets.

Comment: It looks aligned to me. How far is the alignment off? Just by a pixel or two? What platform are you running on?

Comment: Mint 18.1 - Python 3.5.2 - Just a couple of pixel but it's ugly to see. Look at the screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why it's doing that. It displays differently on Windows vs Linux. Never had that problem. What you *can* do is within the combobox grid statement, add padx=1 when a Linux installation is detected, if Windows, no padx if you need multi-platform compatibility. I know this is a workaround, but the fundamental GUI behavior is different between the two systems.

```
import platform
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

os_info = platform.platform()
....

if os_info.startswith('Linux'):
    x.grid(row=3, column=2, columnspan=1, sticky=W, padx=1)
elif os_info.startswith('Windows'):
    x.grid(row=3, column=2, columnspan=1, sticky=W)
...
```