# Left align tkinter widgets using place

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm having some trouble understanding tkinter place coordinates.

As demonstrated by the brilliant visual answer i found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64545215/992644), anchors determine the corner/edge of the object that the coordinates apply to.

Given this fact, then why are my check boxes not vertically aligned when i give them the same x offset and the same anchor.

It seems as if the coordinates are being measured from the center of the object rather than the anchor point, and that center is being calculated based on the length of the text not the w specifed in the place. I have put red dots where I would expect the NW corner of each of the widgets to be.

[image: The reason for my early hairloss]

```
import tkinter as tk

class App:
    def __init__(self, root):
        root.title("Example")
        root.geometry("100x100")
        check_x           = 0
        check_w           = 100
        check_h           = 30
        check_anchor      = 'nw'
        check_j           = 'left'
        check_compound    = 'left'

        ch1               = tk.Checkbutton(root)
        ch1["justify"]    = check_j
        ch1["text"]       = "Top "
        ch1["compound"]   = check_compound
        ch1.place(x       = check_x,
                  y       = 20,
                  width   = check_w,
                  height  = check_h,
                  anchor  = check_anchor)

        ch2              = tk.Checkbutton(root)
        ch2["justify"]   = check_j
        ch2["text"]      = "Bottom"
        ch2["compound"]  = check_compound
        ch2.place(x      = check_x,
                  y      = 50,
                  width  = check_w,
                  height = check_h,
                  anchor = check_anchor)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

This is just an example, in practice i have a more complex GUI with around 30 widgets, I don't need anything at placed at x 0. I just have a few things which I want to be indented and vertically aligned to different horizontal offsets and I want to be able to control this by setting common values across the relevant widgets with a variable.

I can see that this is a common problem beginners have with tkinter, but I couldn't find anyone addressing it in the case of the place method.

- [Alignment of the widgets in Python Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44091064/992644)
- [How to align tkinter widgets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43170320/how-to-align-tkinter-widgets)

Comment: Try removing the `width` option.

Comment: line 17, in __init__
    ch1["compound"]   = check_compound
NameError: name 'check_compound' is not defined. Did you mean: 'ch_compound'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have specify the `width` option of `place()`, the checkbox and the text of the checkbutton will be put in the center within the specified *width* by default.

It is easy to verify that by setting the background color of the checkbuttons:

[image]

Either removing the `width` option of `place()` or adding `anchor = check_anchor` of `Checkbutton()`.

[image]